# htaccess защита

Tags: .htaccess, apache

Здравствуйте, как закрыть доступ или сделать перенаправление при вызове скриптов в папке name с помощью .htaccess. Чтобы скрипт подключался только с помощью iclude php?

Answer (score 1):

Можно так запретить доступ: разместить в этой папке файл **.htaccess** с таким содержимым

```
<Limit GET POST PUT>
Order Allow,Deny
Deny from All
</Limit>
```